# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 33: invalid start byte while reading Matlab files

Tags: python, matlab, utf-8

I am trying to find a missing Matlab Script that i need for some data processing.I wrote some python code to read all the matlab files on the computer system that i am working on since there are thousands of matlab scripts here and i am more comfortable with python than matlab. When i run the code that i wrote to find the string '11-rxnCMP' which must exist in the script that i am looking for, i keep getting this error. The code is below:

```
import os
import codecs 

address = 'X:\Data'
fileNames = []   #contains the full file addresses
OneName = []    #contains individual fileNames
fileCorrect = []
#list all folders to iterate through them later on
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(address):
    for file in os.listdir(subdir):
        if file.endswith(".m"):
            print(subdir,file)
            fileName = file            
            OneName.append(fileName)
            fileAddress = subdir+'/'+ file
            if 'Retired' in fileAddress:
                continue
            else:
                fileNames.append(fileAddress)
#open and read the files that are stored in fileNames

if len(fileNames) != 0:
    for i in range(len(fileNames)):
        lineNum = 0 
        with codecs.open(fileNames[i],mode = 'r', encoding = 'utf8') as fileOpen:
            for line in iter(fileOpen):
                if 'Retired' in fileOpen.name:                
                    break
                else:            
                    lineNum += 1
                    try:
                        if 'rxnCMP' in line:
                            fileCorrect.append(fileNames[i])
                            print(line)
                            print('Script' + fileNames[i] + ' has this word in it ')
                            print(lineNum)
                            continue 
                        else: 
                            continue 
                    except:
                        break
```

The error i get is:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 33: invalid start byte
```

for line:

```
for line in iter(fileOpen)
```

I am not sure why this is is so. Could it be that the matlab scripts that i am writing are encoded differently.

Comment: It may be easier to use `grep` or something else to do this for you rather than brute force checking all files. I think even Window's search allows you to search contents. [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9647-grep--a-pedestrian--very-fast-grep-utility) is a MATLAB-based version of grep

Comment: I thought about that. I didn't use it because i am working with Windows. However, i will into the matlab version of grep you shared.

Comment: You may also use `try` for the `open` call if you know that your file is utf-8 encoded. Then your code will just skip the files with non-unicode characters.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what encoding it would be, i was just playing around with it.

Comment: [`findstr`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) is the relevant Windows command line function.

Comment: Sounds like some of them are indeed encoded differently. Since all you care about is a string that looks like ASCII, you could open them in a single-byte encoding like ASCII or Windows 1252. The high bytes might get decoded incorrectly, but you won't care because your search string won't match them anyway.

But yeah, just use `grep` or the equivalent.